# Multiple binary dummy features Vs Multi-values single feature

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-extraction

I found a script on [Kaggle's titanic competion](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) in wich the creator convert Multi-values single feature (namely Pclass = {1,2,3}) to 3 binary features.

What are the pro/cons of such a conversion? Does it really improve something, or is it worse? Or doesn't change anything?

Despite taking longer to compute, I also worry that it could introduce a bias in the model.

Comment: Note that this is called "one hot encoding".

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question?

Answer (score 1):

As @K3 suggested, as @Sean Owen told me the name (One Hot Encoding), I can provide at least some elements to answer myself.

As found on sklearn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) :

> [...]integer representation can not be used directly with scikit-learn
>   estimators, as these expect continuous input, and would interpret the
>   categories as being ordered, which is often not desired.

It is implemented in sklearn as [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and in Pandas as [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) .